# Error Expression Changed After It Has Been Checked Error Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validación

Tengo un formulario que realice de manera reactivo pero me marca el siguiente error

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'disabled: false'. Current value: 'disabled: true'.
```

En mis validaciones dependiendo de las opciones que se habiliten como por ejemplo:

```
<td *ngIf="this.eleccionMamelones === 'SI'">
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                      <input type="number" formControlName="LongitudMamelon" ngModel matInput placeholder="Longitud">
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </td>
```

si la variable es SI, este aparecerá en la vista, en dado caso de que no sera oculta, y la cual para el formulario elimino la validación de la siguiente manera con el ngIf:

```
    this.inicio.get('CostoMOArillo').clearValidators();
    this.inicio.get('CostoMOArillo').updateValueAndValidity();
```

o en su defecto habilito el componente y vuelvo el formulario valido o invalido según sea el caso
y este des habilita  el botón de insertar  que es donde me da el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la cual no se como solucionarlo

Comment: Agrega el `.ts` completo.

Comment: La directiva `formControlName` pertenece al modulo de formularios reactivos y la directiva `ngModel` al de los dirigidos por plantilla. No deberías mezclar ambos enfoques en un mismo formulario. Si estas usando los formularios reactivos, quita la directiva `ngModel` del input.

Comment: Retirando el ngModel se solucionara o  existe algún inconveniente el que siga estando en el formulario

Answer (score 0):

Usa el metodo `ngAfterInit` y no el `OnInit` para los formularios

Comment: Podrías recomendarme algún lugar donde pueda apoyarme en documentación o articulo te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: @EnriquedeJesusJuarezCruz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513421/ngif-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked